# Gradle 3 breaks call Project.configure()

Tags: gradle

The following works in Gradle 2.13:

```
ext.sharedWarConfig = { task->
    configure(task) {}
}
```

In Gradle 3.0 I am getting error:

> > No signature of method: static org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure() is applicable for argument
> >     types: (build_dke3xcnofl8fbuvcpvgwyc2r5$_run_closure12$_closure38,
> >     com.eriwen.gradle.css.source.internal.DefaultCssSourceSet_Decorated,
> >     java.lang.Boolean) values:
> >     [build_dke3xcnofl8fbuvcpvgwyc2r5$_run_closure12$_closure38@24019438,
> >     ...] Possible solutions: configure(groovy.lang.Closure,
> >     java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 2):

Upgraded gradle-css-plugin to version 2.14.0.

Comment: Maintainer here. Please let me know if you encounter any other issues like this with the CSS or JS plugins. You can find my email on GitHub https://github.com/eriwen